# ng2-datepicker not opening with the values

Tags: angular, ng2-datepicker

I'm trying to use ng2-datepicker. But it is opening like[image]

It should open with the current date. Below is my HTML & TS code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <ng-datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [options]="options"></ng-datepicker>
</div>

options: DatepickerOptions = {
    displayFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
    barTitleFormat: 'MMM YYYY',
    dayNamesFormat: 'dd',
    locale: enLocale,
    minDate: new Date(Date.now()),
};
```

Comment: What does your date-object look like you're binding to via ngModel?

Comment: I have tried with date = new Date()